# Error: Invalid Unity Web File (Decompression Failure)

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

I am getting this error while trying to load asset bundles from server:

> `Exception: WWW download had an error:Invalid Unity Web File (Decompression Failure). URL: http://uehelp.com/testapps/pgift/asset-bundles/test02
>   NonCachingLoadExample+<Start>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () (at Assets/AssetBundlesTest/NonCachingLoadExample.cs:11)`

When I load the asset bundles from my local machine, it works fine.

Comment: Can you, please, share the code how you  are loading the asset bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the asset bundle files are being changed when you are uploading those to the server. May be, if you are using any FTP client like FileZilla, that might be causing the changes.

So please check if the client is uploading the exact file without changing it's file format. The asset bundles are binary file, so this should be uploaded using the same format.

For the case of FileZilla (v3.11.0.1, Mac), please try doing this (other clients should have their similar settings) -

1. Open Settings window
2. Go "Transfers -> File Types"
3. Uncheck "Treat files without extension as ASCII file"
4. You may also need to change other relevant settings depending on your asset bundles file names, so that it must be treated as binary format.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.